# Get /me/events/{id} returns incorrect calendar object

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I tried to fetch list of events from `/me/events?$expand=calendar` endpoint
and it returns correct calendar object in response.

However, when I tried to fetch one particular event, I received a different calendar.
API used: `/me/events/{id}?$expand=calendar`
The user has 4 calendars (verified using /me/calendars). 
And the calendar id received from `/me/events/{id}?$expand=calendar` doesn't match with any of them.

*Edit*

Below are responses for more clarification

1. End point to list all calendars

   ```sh
   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars
   ```

   Response:

   ```
   {
       "value": [
           {
               "id": "<CALENDAR_ID_1>",
               "name": "Calendar",
               "color": "auto",
               "changeKey": "<changeKey>",
               "canShare": true,
               "canViewPrivateItems": true,
               "canEdit": true,
               "owner": {
                   "name": "<Name>",
                   "address": "<Email>"
               }
           },
           {
               "id": "<CALENDAR_ID_2>",
               "name": "Birthdays",
               "color": "auto",
               "changeKey": "<changeKey>",
               "canShare": false,
               "canViewPrivateItems": true,
               "canEdit": false,
               "owner": {
                   "name": "TestVoIP 1",
                   "address": "<Email>"
               }
           },
           ....
       ]
   }
   ```
2. List all events

   ```sh
   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$expand=calendar
   ```

   Response:

   ```
   {
       "value": [
           {
               "id": "<EVENT_ID_1>",
               ... some other properties
               "calendar": {
                   "id": "<CALENDAR_ID_1>", // Note that this is the calendar id for EVENT_ID_1
                   "name": "Calendar",
                   "color": "auto",
                   "changeKey": "<changeKey>",
                   "canShare": true,
                   "canViewPrivateItems": true,
                   "canEdit": true,
                   "owner": {
                       "name": "<Name>",
                       "address": "<Email>"
                   }
               },
           },
           {
               "id": "<EVENT_ID_2>",
               ... some other properties
               "calendar": {
                   "id": "<CALENDAR_ID_1>",
                   "name": "Calendar",
                   "color": "auto",
                   "changeKey": "<changeKey>",
                   "canShare": true,
                   "canViewPrivateItems": true,
                   "canEdit": true,
                   "owner": {
                       "name": "<Name>",
                       "address": "<Email>"
                   }
               },
           },
           ...
       ]
   }
   ```
3. Get event with ID

   ```sh
   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/<EVENT_ID_1>?$expand=calendar
   ```

   Response:

   ```
   {
       "id": "<EVENT_ID_1>",
       ... some other properties
       "calendar": {
           "id": "<DIFFERENT_CALENDAR_ID>", // Note that this is entirely different calendar id than we noted in list of events response AND its not available in list of calendars response too
           "name": null,
           "color": "auto",
           "changeKey": null,
           "canShare": false,
           "canViewPrivateItems": false,
           "canEdit": false,
           "owner": null
       }
   }
   ```